# problems with light in eevee

Tags: rendering, eevee-render-engine, lighting

The lighting in the viewport and in the final render is very different, I tried to change the render parameters, glass textures, refraction settings, but it didn’t work. I would love to hear your suggestions[image]

[image]

Comment: My first thought is that there’s a hidden light source or other object causing a shadow. Have you checked that?

Comment: no, this is not the problem, I already checked it ((